# Difference between -t and -tt ssh

Tags: ssh, shell, tty

`man ssh` says:

> -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a
> remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
> options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-tt

*Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.*

What does that mean specifically? If there is no shell on the system, does ssh create its own? What must happen that -tt fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this:

```
ssh -t user@server<<EOT
echo test
EOT
```

You'll get a message that states: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` In this case, stdin was feeding ssh, not your local shell/tty.

Using `-tt` will tell it to allocate regardless. This is one use-case, I'm sure there are other cases that can be applied to this, but stdin is one of the most obvious.

---

> If there is no shell on the system, does ssh create its own?

No local tty for ssh is not suggesting that a local shell does not exist. The above example shows using stdin to stream into ssh.

> What does that mean specifically?

It means it will force the tty allocation regardless of the local connection. See above example.